# Can we characterize the integer matrices which have cyclic kernel on the real torus?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

By a real torus I mean the Lie group $T = \mathbb{R}^2/\langle e_1,e_2\rangle$ where $e_1 = (1,0)$ and $e_2 = (0,1)$.

Let $M_2(\mathbb{Z})^+$ denote the set of 2x2 integer matrices with positive (hence nonzero) determinant. Given $D\in M_2(\mathbb{Z})^+$ with determinant $n$, it induces a self-map of $T$ with kernel of order $n$.

Is there a nice characterization of the matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})^+$ which have cyclic kernel?

If $D = D_n := [[1,0],[0,n]]$, then it's easy to check that:
$$SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\cap D_n\cdot SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\cdot D_n^{-1} = \Gamma_0(n)$$

Now suppose $D$ is any matrix in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})^+$ with cyclic kernel of order $n$. Is the intersection
$$SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\cap D\cdot SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\cdot D^{-1}$$
always conjugate to $\Gamma_0(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A\in M_2(\Bbb Z)^+$ will have cyclic kernel iff the gcd of its entries
is $1$.

This condition is necessary: if the gcd is $g>1$ then the $g$-torsion of $T$
is contained in the kernel, and the $g$-torsion is non-cyclic.

The condition is sufficient. Consider the Smith normal form $S$ of $A$.
Then the kernel of $S$ will be isomorphic to that of $A$. But if the gcd
is $1$, then $S=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&\det A}$ which has kernel cyclic of
order $\det A$.

In higher dimensions this argument still works: $A\in M_n(\Bbb Z)^+$ will have cyclic
kernel iff the Smith normal form has diagonal entries $1,\ldots,1,\det A$.

Comment: Ah, of course. I guess you could also just note that if the kernel of $D$ is non-cyclic, it must contain the full $k$-torsion, and hence $D$ must factor as $\mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda\stackrel{k}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda\stackrel{A}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda$ for some integer matrix $A$. In this case $k$ must divide all entries of $D$.

Comment: I think more generally, the kernel of $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{k} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\det A / k}$ where $k = \gcd(\{A_{ij}\})$.